# unorderable types: NoneType() < NoneType()

Tags: python

Whenever I enter a value larger than 10 into my cheapest_shipping function it gives an unorderable types error.

I've tried making separate variables to pass to the functions to calculate cost. Also tried different comparison operators.

```
cost = 0
pgs = 125

def gsp(weight):
  if weight == 0:
cost = 20
return cost
  elif weight <= 2:
cost = (1.5 * weight + 20)
return cost 
  elif weight > 2 and weight <= 6:
cost = (3 * weight + 20)
return cost
  elif weight > 6 and weight <= 10:
cost = (4 * weight + 20)
return cost
  elif weight > 10:
cost = (4.75 * weight + 20)

def dsp(weight):
  if weight == 0:
cost = 0
return cost
  elif weight <= 2:
cost = (4.5 * weight)
return cost 
  elif weight > 2 and weight <= 6:
cost = (9 * weight)
return cost
  elif weight > 6 and weight <= 10:
cost = (12 * weight)
return cost
  elif weight > 10:
cost = (14.25 * weight)

def cheapest_shipping(weight):
  if gsp(weight) < dsp(weight) and gsp(weight) < pgs:
return "Ground shipping is the cheapest option at $" + str(gsp(weight))
  elif dsp(weight) < gsp(weight) and dsp(weight) < pgs:
return "Drone shipping is the cheapest option at $" + str(dsp(weight))

print (cheapest_shipping(11))
```

The function uses my ground shipping price function and the drone shipping price function and the cost of premium ground shipping and take the weight input and is supposed to return the cheapest shipping option. Which works until the input is over 10.

Comment: You're missing a `return cost` at the end, and your code is wrongly indented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missing `return cost` in the last `elif` statement.  this may be what you want

```
cost = 0
pgs = 125


def gsp(weight):
    if weight == 0:
        cost = 20
        return cost
    elif weight <= 2:
        cost = (1.5 * weight + 20)
        return cost
    elif weight > 2 and weight <= 6:
        cost = (3 * weight + 20)
        return cost
    elif weight > 6 and weight <= 10:
        cost = (4 * weight + 20)
        return cost
    elif weight > 10:
        cost = (4.75 * weight + 20)
        return cost


def dsp(weight):
    if weight == 0:
        cost = 0
        return cost
    elif weight <= 2:
        cost = (4.5 * weight)
        return cost
    elif 2 < weight <= 6:
        cost = (9 * weight)
        return cost
    elif 6 < weight <= 10:
        cost = (12 * weight)
        return cost
    elif weight > 10:
        cost = (14.25 * weight)
        return cost


def cheapest_shipping(weight):
    if gsp(weight) < dsp(weight) and gsp(weight) < pgs:
        return "Ground shipping is the cheapest option at $" + str(gsp(weight))
    elif dsp(weight) < gsp(weight) and dsp(weight) < pgs:
        return "Drone shipping is the cheapest option at $" + str(dsp(weight))


print (cheapest_shipping(11))
```